# PIG: how the map-side join works?

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera

In MapReduce, the requirements for a map-side join are:

- Data should be partitioned and sorted in particular way.
- Each input data should be divided in same number of partition.
- Must be sorted with same key.
- All the records for a particular key must reside in the same partition.

I have a simple PIG script:

```
 A = LOAD '/input_01/*.parquet' using parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();   
 B = LOAD '/input_02/*.parquet' using parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();

 C = JOIN A BY id, B BY id;

 STORE C into '/output' using parquet.pig.ParquetStorer();
```

After running this script, the console output told me that such *INNER JOIN* results in a *MAP SIDE HASH JOIN*.

However, as far as I know, my inputs data-sets aren't sorted on a particular key, and I don't know about partitions.

In such conditions, how PIG could success to do a Map Side Join ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you please copy and paste whats written in console ? I dont think that Pig write the used join type !

Comment: I recently noticed that using a merged join did not have a significant impact on the runtime of one script. As such I suspect that pig itself may sometimes be able to optimize simple joins 'under the hood'. (Definitely just a suspicion at this point though.)